# I want to make a 3d carousel like the demo design attached

Tags: flutter, dart

Are there any packages in flutter to make this type of 3d carousel slider?

[image]

Comment: I think you can build upon this: https://mightytechno.com/flutter-flip-card-animation-with-3d-effect/ and change it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You requirement is a little like ipod coverflow, this is quite close to what you need, [perspective_pageview](https://pub.dev/packages/perspective_pageview):

```
Container(
          child: Center(
            // Adding Child Widget of Perspective PageView
            child: PerspectivePageView(
              hasShadow: true, // Enable-Disable Shadow
              shadowColor: Colors.black12, // Change Color
              aspectRatio: PVAspectRatio.ONE_ONE, // Aspect Ratio of 1:1 (Default)
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint("Statement One");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint("Statement Two");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
              ],

            ),
          ),
        ),
```